How do I solve this issue "object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found"?
I'm trying to restore the project Scala IDE to make it work on a more recent technical environment, i.e. Eclipse 2024-03, JDK17, and Scala 2.12.19.
I'm launching the test suite of this eclipse plugin project with org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:4.0.7:test.
The configuration of the tycho-surefire-plugin is :
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
      <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <useUIHarness>false</useUIHarness>
        <useUIThread>false</useUIThread>
        <systemProperties combine.children="append">
          <aj.weaving.verbose>true</aj.weaving.verbose>
          <org.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo>true</org.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo>
          <org.aspectj.osgi.verbose>true</org.aspectj.osgi.verbose>
        </systemProperties>
        <frameworkExtensions>
          <frameworkExtension>
            <groupId>p2.osgi.bundle</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook</artifactId>
            <version>${weaving.hook.plugin.version}</version>
          </frameworkExtension>
        </frameworkExtensions>
        <bundleStartLevel>
          <bundle>
            <id>org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj</id>
            <level>2</level>
            <autoStart>true</autoStart>
          </bundle>
        </bundleStartLevel>
        <argLine>${tycho.test.jvmArgs}</argLine>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>

The root project defines properties :
<weaving.hook.plugin.version>1.4.0.v20240213-1357</weaving.hook.plugin.version>
<tycho.test.weaving>-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -Dosgi.classloader.lock=classname</tycho.test.weaving>
<tycho.test.addOpens>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</tycho.test.addOpens>
<tycho.test.jvmArgs>${tycho.test.addOpens} -Xmx2048m -Dsdtcore.headless -Dsdtcore.notimeouts -DretryFlakyTests=true ${tycho.test.weaving}</tycho.test.jvmArgs>

The tycho-surefire-plugin launched the following java command:
C:\Users\nicol\Downloads\jdk-17.0.4_windows-x64_bin\jdk-17.0.4\bin\java.exe -Dosgi.noShutdown=false -Dosgi.os=win32 -Dosgi.ws=win32 -Dosgi.arch=x86_64 --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx2048m -Dsdtcore.headless -Dsdtcore.notimeouts -DretryFlakyTests=true -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -Dosgi.classloader.lock=classname -Dosgi.clean=true -Daj.weaving.verbose=true -Dorg.aspectj.osgi.verbose=true -Dorg.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo=true -jar C:\Users\nicol.m2\repository\p2\osgi\bundle\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher\1.6.700.v20240213-1244\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher-1.6.700.v20240213-1244.jar -data C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests\target\work\data -install C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests\target\work -configuration C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests\target\work\configuration -application org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.headlesstest -testproperties C:\Users\nicol\git\scala-ide\org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests\target\surefire.properties

One of the test classes is :
package org.scalaide.core.testsetup


import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IncrementalProjectBuilder
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.NullProgressMonitor
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IPackageFragmentRoot
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IProblemRequestor
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.WorkingCopyOwner
import org.eclipse.text.edits.ReplaceEdit
import org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull
import org.mockito.Mockito.mock
import org.mockito.Mockito.when
import org.scalaide.core.compiler.InteractiveCompilationUnit
import org.scalaide.core.internal.jdt.model.ScalaCompilationUnit
import org.scalaide.core.internal.jdt.model.ScalaSourceFile
import org.scalaide.core.IScalaProject
import org.scalaide.core.internal.project.ScalaProject

/** Base class for setting up tests that depend on a project found in the test-workspace.
 *
 *  Subclass this class with an `object'. The initialization will copy the given project
 *  from test-workspace to the target workspace, and retrieve the 'src/' package root in
 *  `srcPackageRoot'.
 *
 *  Reference the object form your test, so that the constructor is called and the project
 *  setup.
 *
 *  Example: `object HyperlinkDetectorTests extends TestProjectSetup("hyperlinks")'
 *
 */
class TestProjectSetup(projectName: String, srcRoot: String = "/%s/src/", val bundleName: String = "org.scala-ide.sdt.core.tests") extends ProjectBuilder {
  private[core] lazy val internalProject: ScalaProject = BlockingProgressMonitor.waitUntilDone {
    SDTTestUtils.internalSetupProject(projectName, bundleName)(_)
  }

  /** The ScalaProject corresponding to projectName, after copying to the test workspace. */
  override lazy val project: IScalaProject = internalProject

  /** The package root corresponding to /src inside the project. */
  lazy val srcPackageRoot: IPackageFragmentRoot = {
    val javaProject = JavaCore.create(project.underlying)

    javaProject.open(null)
    javaProject.findPackageFragmentRoot(new Path(srcRoot.format(projectName)))
  }

  assertNotNull(srcPackageRoot)

  srcPackageRoot.open(null)

  def file(path: String): IFile = {
    project.underlying.getFile(path)
  }

  /** Return the compilation unit corresponding to the given path, relative to the src folder.
   *  for example: "scala/collection/Map.scala"
   */
  def compilationUnit(path: String): ICompilationUnit = {
    val segments = path.split("/")
    srcPackageRoot.getPackageFragment(segments.init.mkString(".")).getCompilationUnit(segments.last)
  }

  /** Return a sequence of compilation units corresponding to the given paths. */
  def compilationUnits(paths: String*): Seq[ICompilationUnit] =
    paths.map(compilationUnit)

  /** Return a sequence of Scala compilation units corresponding to the given paths. */
  def scalaCompilationUnits(paths: String*): Seq[ScalaSourceFile] =
    paths.map(scalaCompilationUnit)

  /** Return the Scala compilation unit corresponding to the given path, relative to the src folder.
   *  for example: "scala/collection/Map.scala".
   */
  def scalaCompilationUnit(path: String): ScalaSourceFile =
    compilationUnit(path).asInstanceOf[ScalaSourceFile]

  def createSourceFile(packageName: String, unitName: String)(contents: String): ScalaSourceFile = {
    val pack = SDTTestUtils.createSourcePackage(packageName)(project)
    SDTTestUtils.createCompilationUnit(pack, unitName, contents).asInstanceOf[ScalaSourceFile]
  }

  def reload(unit: InteractiveCompilationUnit): Unit = {
    // first, 'open' the file by telling the compiler to load it
    unit.withSourceFile { (src, compiler) =>
      compiler.askReload(List(unit)).get
    }
  }

  def parseAndEnter(unit: InteractiveCompilationUnit): Unit = {
    unit.withSourceFile { (src, compiler) =>
      val dummy = new compiler.Response[compiler.Tree]
      compiler.askParsedEntered(src, false, dummy)
      dummy.get
    }
  }

  def findMarker(marker: String) = SDTTestUtils.findMarker(marker)

  /** Emulate the opening of a scala source file (i.e., it tries to
   * reproduce the steps performed by JDT when opening a file in an editor).
   *
   * @param srcPath the path to the scala source file
   * */
  def open(srcPath: String): ScalaSourceFile = {
    val unit = scalaCompilationUnit(srcPath)
    openWorkingCopyFor(unit)
    reload(unit)
    unit
  }

  /** Open a working copy of the passed `unit` */
  private def openWorkingCopyFor(unit: ScalaSourceFile): Unit = {
    val requestor = mock(classOf[IProblemRequestor])
    // the requestor must be active, or unit.getWorkingCopy won't trigger the Scala
    // structure builder
    when(requestor.isActive()).thenReturn(true)

    val owner = new WorkingCopyOwner() {
      override def getProblemRequestor(unit: org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit): IProblemRequestor = requestor
    }

    // this will trigger the Scala structure builder
    unit.getWorkingCopy(owner, new NullProgressMonitor)
  }

  /** Wait until the passed `unit` is entirely typechecked. */
  def waitUntilTypechecked(unit: ScalaCompilationUnit): Unit = {
    // give a chance to the background compiler to report the error
    unit.withSourceFile { (source, compiler) =>
      compiler.askLoadedTyped(source, true).get // wait until unit is typechecked
    }
  }

  /** Open the passed `source` and wait until it has been fully typechecked.*/
  def openAndWaitUntilTypechecked(source: ScalaSourceFile): Unit = {
    val sourcePath = source.getPath()
    val projectSrcPath = project.underlying.getFullPath() append "src"
    val path = sourcePath.makeRelativeTo(projectSrcPath)
    open(path.toOSString())
    waitUntilTypechecked(source)
  }

  /**
   * Allows to modify sources in test workspace.
   *
   * @param compilationUnitPath path to file which we'll change
   * @param lineNumber line which will be removed (line numbers start from 1)
   * @param newLine code inserted in place of line with lineNumber
   */
  def modifyLine(compilationUnitPath: String, lineNumber: Int, newLine: String): Unit = {
    val lineIndex = lineNumber - 1
    val cu = compilationUnit(compilationUnitPath)
    val code = cu.getSource
    val lines = code.split('\n').toList
    val newLines = lines.updated(lineIndex, newLine)
    val newCode = newLines.mkString("\n")

    val textEdit = new ReplaceEdit(0, code.length(), newCode)
    cu.applyTextEdit(textEdit, new NullProgressMonitor)
    cu.save(new NullProgressMonitor, true)
  }

  /**
   * Be aware that it can be heavy. Moreover, it's needed to ensure that
   * events are already properly propagated after the build.
   */
  def buildIncrementally(): Unit =
    project.underlying.build(IncrementalProjectBuilder.INCREMENTAL_BUILD, new NullProgressMonitor)
}

The stacktrace corresponding to that test is  :
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
        at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:24)
        at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:25)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.$anonfun$getModuleOrClass$5(Mirrors.scala:61)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:61)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:51)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredClass(Mirrors.scala:51)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:301)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:301)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1511)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1225)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global$TyperRun.<init>(Global.scala:1323)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global.newTyperRun(Global.scala:1346)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global.<init>(Global.scala:294)
        at org.scalaide.core.internal.compiler.ScalaPresentationCompiler.<init>(ScalaPresentationCompiler.scala:55)
        at org.scalaide.core.internal.compiler.PresentationCompilerProxy.liftedTree1$1(PresentationCompilerProxy.scala:156)
        at org.scalaide.core.internal.compiler.PresentationCompilerProxy.create(PresentationCompilerProxy.scala:153)
        at org.scalaide.core.internal.compiler.PresentationCompilerProxy.initialize(PresentationCompilerProxy.scala:118)
        at org.scalaide.core.internal.compiler.PresentationCompilerProxy.obtainPc$1(PresentationCompilerProxy.scala:80)
        at org.scalaide.core.internal.compiler.PresentationCompilerProxy.internal(PresentationCompilerProxy.scala:100)
        at org.scalaide.core.internal.compiler.PresentationCompilerProxy.apply(PresentationCompilerProxy.scala:58)
        at org.scalaide.core.compiler.InteractiveCompilationUnit.withSourceFile(InteractiveCompilationUnit.scala:201)
        at org.scalaide.core.compiler.InteractiveCompilationUnit.withSourceFile$(InteractiveCompilationUnit.scala:200)
        at org.scalaide.core.internal.jdt.model.ScalaSourceFile.withSourceFile(ScalaSourceFile.scala:70)
        at org.scalaide.core.testsetup.TestProjectSetup.reload(TestProjectSetup.scala:88)
        at org.scalaide.core.completion.CompletionTests.t1001218(CompletionTests.scala:161)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:316)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:240)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:155)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.api.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter.run(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.HeadlessTestApplication.start(HeadlessTestApplication.java:29)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:208)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:439)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:271)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:651)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:588)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1459)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1432)

The target-platform-configuration uses a target-platform file target-platform-2.12.target :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target name="target-platform">
  <locations>
    <location includeDependencyDepth="none" includeSource="true"
      missingManifest="generate" type="Maven">
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
          <version>2.12.19</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
          <version>2.12.19</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
          <version>2.12.19</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.scala-refactoring</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.scala-refactoring.library_2.12.2</artifactId>
          <version>0.13.0</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.scalariform</groupId>
          <artifactId>scalariform_2.12</artifactId>
          <version>0.2.10</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang.modules</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-xml_2.12</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.0</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.scala-ide</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.scala-ide.zinc.compiler.bridge</artifactId>
          <version>4.7.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.scala-ide</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.scala-ide.zinc.library</artifactId>
          <version>4.7.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.fusesource.jansi</groupId>
          <artifactId>jansi</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </location>
    <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
      <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2024-03"/>
      <unit id="org.apache.ant" version="0.0.0"/>
    </location>
  </locations>
</target>

I tried to do minimalist example without tycho/osgi and I didn't have any issue with it :
import scala.tools.nsc.Global
import scala.tools.nsc.Settings

object ScalaCompiler {
  def compileScalaFile(fileName: String): Unit = {
    val settings = new Settings()
    settings.usejavacp.value = true
    settings.withErrorFn(err => println(s"error while compiling: $err"))

    val compiler = new Global(settings)
    val run = new compiler.Run
    val sourceFiles = run.compile(List(fileName))
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    if (args.length > 0) {
      compileScalaFile(args(0))
    } else {
      println("No filename provided. Usage: scala ScalaCompiler <filename>")
    }
  }
}

class Test {
   println ("Hello World!")
}

This worked without any errors :
scalac ScalaCompiler.scala

java -cp .;.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.12.19\scala-library-2.12.19.jar;.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.12.19\scala-compiler-2.12.19.jar;.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.12.19\scala-reflect-2.12.19.jar ScalaCompiler Test.scala

I suspect there is something with the OSGi environment that prevents java.lang.Object from being visible by the scala compiler.
